# How to construct queryParam in spring boot webclient dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, query-string, spring-webclient

I need to call a microservice using WebClient in spring boot. I want to make a generic method which will take a Map as an input and set the query params dynamically
Currently the below code works fine.

```
private WebClient getWebClient(){
return WebClient.create(“http://www.example.com”);
}

public String get(){ 
return webclient.get()
.uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
    .queryParam(“key”,”value”)
    .queryParam(“key1”,1)
    .build())
 .retrieve()
 .bodyToMono(String.class)
 .block();
}
```

To make the method **get** generic I want to build the queryParam from a Map, e.g.

```
public <T> T getCommon(Map<String,Object>,Map<String,Object> queryParams, Class<T> toObject){

return webclient.get()
.uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
    // Form the query param from the queryParams Map which is coming as an argument of the method
    .build())
 .retrieve()
 .bodyToMono(toObject)
 .block();
}
```

MultiValueMap will not work as it takes <String,String>, but my Map can contain String,Integer as value.
Example:

```
Map<String,Object> queryParams=new HashMap<>();
queryParams.put(“key1”,”value1”);
queryParams.put(“key1”,20);
```

How to achieve the same as above?
Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: You can just make your generic function take in a functional interface, and instead of passing in a map, each user has to pass in a lambda.